# Baremetal IBM Power Server not seen in Rest Response

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

```
https://<username>:<password>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getObject.json?
```

While querying for the "IBM Power" Servers from the Softlayer Packages , I do not see the IBM Power servers , however all the other Intel Server are listed. Please help with the Rest call to get all the "IBM Power Servers" for a region. e.g dal09.

Answer (score 0):

To order servers there are several packages you can get all the packages avaialbe for Bare metals using this request:

```
GET https://$USER:APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects
```

The you can look up in the result the flavor that you want, it seems that the package you are looking for is the package 242 so you should change the value "200" by "242" in your request

Regards